# How to get rid of right margin in last item of navigation bar using last child

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I have created a navigation bar and have added `margin-right` to all the items.

However, when I try to get rid of the margin right in the last child of the navigation item "contact", it won't disappear.

```css
.navbar {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-list {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-list li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.nav-list ul li a:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.nav-list li a:active {
  color: #000;
}

.nav-list li a:visited {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home">Home</li></a>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#about">About</li></a>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#work">Work</li></a>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#services">Services</li></a>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</li></a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Here is my code pen: https://codepen.io/derrickogole/pen/rNxbaaK

Is there a way to do this without adding an additional class to contact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) psuedo-class.

```css
.nav-item:last-child a {
  margin: 0;
}
```

See it here:

```css
.navbar {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-list {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-list li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.nav-list ul li a:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.nav-list li a:active {
  color: #000;
}

.nav-list li a:visited {
  color: #000;
}

.nav-item:last-child a {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Additionally, your markup was invalid due to closing `</li>` before `</a>`. `a` is nested in `li` so it needs to be closed first.